# A policy iteration problem in reinforcement learning

Tags: java, reinforcement-learning

I have to solve a problem with policy iteration, the model is showed in

[image]

and I make a Java program to simulate, the policy algorithm is based on Sutton and Barto's book on [Reinforcement learning](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node43.html). 
I am confident the model in the java program is consistent with the model in the picture.
When I finally run the simulation, I can do the iteration in 4 times, and the final result is right with final answer in the textbook. But in the textbook, the final answer takes only three iterations, although the final answer is right, the intermediate answer in the iteration has minor changes, I don't know what is the problem?

```
public class PolicyIteration{

    private static final double TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    private double gamma = 0.9;

    private int stateCount = 5;
    private int actionCount = 7;

    //states names
    private final String s[] = {"s1","s2","s3","s4","s5"};
    private final String ac[] = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"};
    // states
    private final int s1 =0;
    private final int s2 =1;
    private final int s3 = 2;
    private final int s4 = 3;
    private final int s5 = 4;

    // actions 
    private final int a = 0;
    private final int b = 1;
    private final int c = 2;
    private final int d = 3;
    private final int e = 4;
    private final int f = 5;
    private final int g = 6;

    // transition
    private double t[][][] = new double[stateCount][stateCount][actionCount];
    // rewards
    private double r[][][] = new double[stateCount][stateCount][actionCount];    
    // utility
    private double values[] = new double[stateCount];
    // policy
    private int policy[] = new int[stateCount];
    // init

    private void init(){        
        for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
            values[i] = 0;
        }       
        //(s1; a); (s2; c); (s3; e); (s4; f); (s5; g)
        policy[s1] = a; policy[s2] = c; policy[s3] = e; policy[s4] = f;  policy[s5] = g;
        //
        t[s1][s2][a] = 1;  r[s1][s2][a] = 0;
        t[s1][s3][b] = 1;  r[s1][s3][b] = 0;
        t[s2][s2][c] = 0.5;  r[s2][s2][c] = 0;
        t[s2][s4][c] = 0.5;  r[s2][s4][c] = 0;
        t[s3][s3][e] = 1;  r[s3][s3][e] = 1;
        t[s4][s5][f] = 1;  r[s4][s5][f] = 0;
        t[s4][s4][d] = 1;  r[s4][s4][d] = 10;
        t[s5][s5][g] = 1;  r[s5][s5][g] = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        PolicyIteration p = new PolicyIteration();
        p.init();
        p.run();
    }


    public void run(){
        int it = 0;

        int changed= 1;
        do{
            it++;
            System.out.println("Iteration :"+it);
            changed = train();

            for(int i=0;i<policy.length;i++){
                System.out.print( s[i]+"->" + ac[ policy[i] ]  +" ; ");
            }

            System.out.println();

            for(int i=0;i<policy.length;i++)
            System.out.print(values[i]+" ,");

            System.out.println();
        }while(changed>0);

    }

    public int train() {

        boolean valuesChanged = false;
        do {
            valuesChanged = false;
            // loop through all the states
            for (int i = 0; i < stateCount; i++) {
                // calculate the new value
                int action = policy[i];
                double actionVal = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < stateCount; j++) {
                    actionVal += t[i][j][action]*(r[i][j][action] + gamma* values[j]);
                }
                // check if we're done
                if (Math.abs(values[i] - actionVal) > TOLERANCE) {
                    valuesChanged = true;
                }
                values[i] = actionVal;
            }
        } while (valuesChanged);
        int changed = 0;
        // calculate the new policy
        for (int i = 0; i < stateCount; i++) {
            // find the maximum action
            double maxActionVal = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
            int maxAction = 0;
            for (int action = 0; action < actionCount; action++) {
                double actionVal = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < stateCount; j++) {
                    actionVal += t[i][j][action]*(r[i][j][action] + gamma* values[j]);                          
                }                
                if (actionVal >= maxActionVal) {
                    maxActionVal = actionVal;
                    maxAction = action;
                }

                if(i==s5 && action == g){
                    System.out.println("----  actionVal:"+actionVal+"    "+action);
                }
            }
            if (policy[i] != maxAction) {
                changed++;
                policy[i] = maxAction;
            }
        }
        return changed;
    }


}
```

The answer in the textbook , is

```
Initial policy:
s1 best action: a
s2 best action: c
s3 best action: e
s4 best action: f
s5 best action: g
After policy evaluation:
s1 value: 0.000
s2 value: 0.000
s3 value: 9.114
s4 value: 0.000
s5 value: 0.000
== End of iteration 1 ==

new policy:
s1 best action: b
s2 best action: c
s3 best action: e
s4 best action: d
s5 best action: g
After policy evaluation:
s1 value: 8.992
s2 value: 80.945
s3 value: 9.992
s4 value: 99.127
s5 value: 0.000
== End of iteration 2 ==

new policy:
s1 best action: a
s2 best action: c
s3 best action: e
s4 best action: d
s5 best action: g
After policy evaluation:
s1 value: 72.929
s2 value: 81.111
s3 value: 9.994
s4 value: 99.293
s5 value: 0.000
== End of iteration 3 ==
```